# Move MS Office from one Computer to another

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, license-key

I have this annoying problem. 
I have a client that is using MS office 2013 Home & Business and want to move the programs to his other computer, since he bought a new one. He added the license key to a MS account and downloaded office a year ago, although he **cannot remember his MS account or locate the license key.**

Is there a way to locate the license key or MS account that was used to install MS office a year ago? 
Or is there any other way to move the office programs?

Thanks!

/Andreas

Comment: if he's in the habit of saving passwords he might be able to login to his MS account with a saved password.. the user is usually an email address (I think), and when he made the account there are recovery options associated with it, so he can get a new password. Here is MS info from their site https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-your-Office-product-key-after-installation-026bc81b-6b2f-4052-b433-f41e6cc31c5a

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a new product key by contacting North America Customer Service (NACS) at (800) 936-5700. A new key can be generated only if you have retail copy of the software (DVD) or downloaded version through Digital River or Microsoft Store.

Note There may be a charge to obtain a new product key from Microsoft ACS.

taken from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2279109

Comment: The client is going to need at least part of the license key in order to be helped.